# load select box with a selected option using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have come across a problem now I do have a solution however it involves many of if statements and I would like to know it there is a neater option

what I would like is

```
<select>
<option value ="00:00">00:00</option>
<option value ="01:00">01:00</option>
<option value ="02:00">02:00</option>
<option value ="03:00">03:00</option>
</select>
```

then get an value from and have that box selected
what I'm am currently thinking is

```
$selectedbox = array();
if($tablevalue == "00:00"){
$selectedbox[0] = 'selected="selected"';
}
if($tablevalue == "01:00"){
$selectedbox[1] = 'selected="selected"';
}
```

then have

```
<select>
<option value ="00:00" <?php echo $selectedbox[0]; ?>>00:00</option>
<option value ="01:00" <?php echo $selectedbox[1]; ?>>01:00</option>
<option value ="02:00" <?php echo $selectedbox[2]; ?>>02:00</option>
<option value ="03:00" <?php echo $selectedbox[3]; ?>>03:00</option>
</select>
```

is there an easier way of getting the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $sel = ("0{$i}:00" == $tablevalue) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo <<<EOL
<option value="0{$i}:00"{$sel}>0{$i}:00</option>

EOL;
}
```

Comment: This is what I would actually do in this case. It works if the options are an incremental number (or already in an array you can foreach over). If the data isn't a number/array, then I would suggest using the ternary statement as I answered.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the `if` statements and put the code inline with the option tag with a ternary. Ex:

```
<select>
<option value ="00:00" <?=$tablevalue=="00:00"?'selected="selected"':''?>>00:00</option>
<option value ="01:00" <?=$tablevalue=="01:00"?'selected="selected"':''?>>01:00</option>
<option value ="02:00" <?=$tablevalue=="02:00"?'selected="selected"':''?>>02:00</option>
<option value ="03:00" <?=$tablevalue=="03:00"?'selected="selected"':''?>>03:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at PHP `switch` statements: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

I think you would want something like this:

```
switch ($tablevalue) {
    case "00:00":
        $selectedbox[0] = 'selected="selected"';
        break;
    case "01:00":
        $selectedbox[0] = 'selected="selected"';
        break;
    //etc, etc
}
```

PHP `switch` is a better way to handle if statements if you're always comparing the same variable.